# A word for "could erupt at any time"

Tags: single-word-requests

Close to "volatile", but not in the sense that it's unstable or sensitive. More like a volcano or a geyser that could erupt at potentially any time, or one of those popper things you flip upside down and stick on the ground, and it pops up without warning.

Comment: Would you say that it's at **bursting point**?

Comment: An *imminent eruption*.

Comment: With reference to volcanos and geysers 'active' is the term used.

Comment: Those were just examples. It could be used to describe an overdue earthquake, bottled up emotions, or the cold war.

Comment: The term might be 'labile': 'liable to change'. That's generally used technically, though.

Comment: Surely a volcano (and even more literally a popper) is precisely *unstable*. What more do you want from the word?

Comment: "Unstable" might suit your needs.

Comment: You can consider *time bomb* or *ticking time bomb*. OED definition: "*fig.* A person or thing regarded as likely to lead to or cause a sudden catastrophic event at some point in the future."

Comment: *pent up*.......

Answer (score 1):

"could erupt at any time" adj
"like a volcano or a geyser that.." adj
"volatile" adj

> could erupt at potentially any time

I interpret these meanings:

1. Potential is due to absence of negative evidence. The predictability of the subject has not been obtained. So a state of potential is assumed.
2. Potential is due to positive evidence. There's a guarantee of the state of possibility (of eruption).
3. *Any time* is inaccurately intended to mean readily available eruptive quality.

2 I believe you'd like "potential eruption" as an adjective. For that I think that **active** is the best word. It has a `potential` and `eruptive` association within volcanology.

Oxford English Dictionary 2nd Edition:

> 5a **Active** adj : Opposed to sluggish or inert: Abounding in action; energetic, lively, agile, nimble; diligent, busy, brisk. (Of persons and things.)

oxforddictionaries.com

> 3.3(Of a volcano) currently erupting, or that has erupted within historical times. Often contrasted with dormant or extinct.

merriam-webster.com

> 8a :  disposed to action :  energetic (took an active interest)
>   b :  engaged in an action or activity (an active club member)
>   c (of a volcano) :  currently erupting or likely to erupt

3 Although *active* implies positive potentiality, it doesn't imply urgency. To add urgency to the word, you can use *imminence*. Concatenate the two, to imply an urgent state of activity.

> **Imminoactive** adj. : That in which an eruption sequence has commenced.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with  Tim Lymington's comment that *unstable* works extremely well as a single word meaning "could erupt at potentially any time." To support that view with some real-world examples, I offer these instances from a Google Books search for "unstable" + "could erupt."

From Richard Fleming & Tom Monte, [*Stop Inflammation Now!*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tw0lvr-34pQC&pg=PA108&dq=unstable+%22could+erupt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzI2y18DJAhXQhoMKHVRYAWgQ6AEISjAI#v=onepage&q=unstable%20%22could%20erupt%22&f=false) (2005):

> "Your high cholesterol and angina mean that your heart is not getting enough oxygen. That means the plaques in your arteries are probably unstable. At the same time, you've got a lot of inflammation going on in your arteries. That means the plaques in your arteries are probably **unstable**. One of those plaques **could erupt** when you least expect it. It could form a clot and you could have a fatal heart attack."

From Hermn Kahn, [*On Thermonuclear War*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qX7YAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA362&dq=unstable+%22could+erupt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzI2y18DJAhXQhoMKHVRYAWgQ6AEIRDAH#v=onepage&q=unstable%20%22could%20erupt%22&f=false) (2007):

> Many people realized then that the basic situation [prior to World War I] was **unstable** and that a chain of events **could erupt** into a conflagration, but I think relatively few people took the possibility seriously; that is, few of the decision makers “cared” until events had gone too far.

From Jon Erickson, [*Environmental Geology: Facing the Challenges of Our Changing Earth*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFTxRdqBZCYC&pg=PA234&dq=unstable+%22could+erupt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzI2y18DJAhXQhoMKHVRYAWgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=unstable%20%22could%20erupt%22&f=false) (2009):

> Tapping into this enormous energy storehouse, however, is costly and potentially dangerous. If the methane hydrate becomes **unstable**, it **could erupt** like a volcano. Several craters on the ocean floor are identified as having been caused by gas blowouts. Giant plumes of methane have been observed rising from the seabed.

From Frank Peretti, [*The Cooper Kids Adventure Series 2-in-1 Book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xa1o2oIEEA8C&pg=PA108&dq=unstable+%22could+erupt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzI2y18DJAhXQhoMKHVRYAWgQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=unstable%20%22could%20erupt%22&f=false) (2010):

> "Good thing the villagers are coming back," said Dr. Henderson. "That thing's [that is, "The Stone is"] **unstable**. It **could erupt**; it could topple; pieces of it could break off. ... We don't know *what* it could do."

From John Donoghue, [*Police, Lies & Alibis: The True Story of a Front Line Officer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=o2_XBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=unstable+%22could+erupt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzI2y18DJAhXQhoMKHVRYAWgQ6AEIODAF#v=onepage&q=unstable%20%22could%20erupt%22&f=false) (2013):

> Oxley was a volatile and **unstable** man who **could erupt** at any moment.

These are five of the first ten matches that my search returned (out of a total of about 250), and they link *unstable* and the prospect of eruption in the context of heart disease, world war, methane hydrate, a mountainous stone, and an unpredictable human being. I think it's a good indication of how suitable *unstable* is as a descriptive term for something that could erupt at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the analogy of a volcano anyway, you might just want to "go for it" by using the adjectival form **volcanic.** That would describe "could erupt at any time." [Volcanoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcano) do, in fact, have this "firecracker" property.

Answer (score 0):

> More like a volcano or a geyser that could erupt at potentially any time.

Volcanic eruptions be unpredictable, none could have been predicted at any time.

Comment: I believe OP is looking for a single word that describes this kind of activity.

Comment: I thought I was highlighting the contradiction in OP' sentence.

Comment: I read the question again and realized it had nothing to do with volcanoes, but sought instead to find a synonym close to volatile that carries a sense of volcanic explosions and hyperfertility. Some kind of mutant?